# Mocking a Fluent interface using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, fluent

I have looked at a number of questions here on this subject but none seem to address the issue I'm having.

I've got code that looks a bit like this...

```
IBaseDataCollector<MyClass> myDataCollector;

myDataCollector = new Mock<IBaseDataCollector<MyClass>>();

systemUnderTest = new Thing(myDataCollector.Object);
```

And in my `Thing` class...

```
var collection = myDataCollector.SomeMethod()
                     .SomeSecondMethod()
                     .GetData();
```

where both `SomeMethod()` and `SomeSecondMethod()` return `this` (ie the instance of `myDataCollector`)

When I run my test I get a `NullReferenceException` on the like where I call `myDataCollector`.

I tried adding this in my test setup...

```
myDataCollector.Setup(_=> _.SomeMethod()),Returns(myDataCollector.Object);
```

but that wouldn't even compile, complaining that it "Could not resolve method 'Returns(IBaseDataCollector)'"

Now, if I refactor my `Thing` class to read...

```
myDataCollector.SomeMethod();
myDataCollector.SomeSecondMethod()
var collection = myDataCollector.GetData();
```

my test executes properly.

If this was it, I'd just refactor my code and get on with life, but, in reality, I need to call my code inside a `SelectMany` call...

```
var collection = list.SelectMany(_=> myDataCollector.SomeMethod()
                     .SomeSecondMethod(_)
                     .GetData());
```

Again, I know I *could* replace the `SelectMany` with, say, a `ForEach` and manually populate the collection with the results of each iteration of the call to `GetData()` so that I can get rid of the fluent element of the calls, but this means refactoring the code just to make the tests work, which feels wrong.

How should I be calling `Setup()` on my Mocked objects to make my fluent calls work?

Comment: Maybe `SetReturnsDefault` could help. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166512/how-to-moq-fluent-interface-chain-methods/56172661#56172661

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following test code (I've invented some details to fill in the blanks). The mocked object instance should be available as a value to return from its own methods as shown.

```
    public class UnitTestExample
    {

        [Fact]
        public void UnitTestExample1()
        {
            var myClassInterfaceMock = new Mock<IInterface<MyClass>>();
            var instance = myClassInterfaceMock.Object;
            var myList = new List<MyClass>()
            {
                new MyClass() { Attribute = 1 }
            };

            myClassInterfaceMock.Setup(_ => _.SomeMethod()).Returns(instance);
            myClassInterfaceMock.Setup(_ => _.SomeSecondMethod()).Returns(instance);
            myClassInterfaceMock.Setup(_ => _.GetData()).Returns(myList);

            var myDependentClass = new MyDependentClass(instance);
            var result = myDependentClass.DoTheThing();

            Assert.True(result.Count.Equals(1));
        }
    }

    public interface IInterface<T>
    {
        IInterface<T> SomeMethod();
        IInterface<T> SomeSecondMethod();
        List<T> GetData();
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Attribute { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDependentClass
    {
        private readonly IInterface<MyClass> _test;

        public MyDependentClass(IInterface<MyClass> test)
        {
            _test = test;
        }

        public List<MyClass> DoTheThing()
        {
            return _test.SomeMethod().SomeSecondMethod().GetData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adam, I was still getting the "Cannot Resolve" error when I tried setting it out like you did. Then I noticed that in my Interface my fluent calls were returning ```BaseDataCollector<T>``` rather than ```IBaseDataCollector<T>```. That said, _if_ I had found the solution at all, it would have taken a lot longer without the effort you put in. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked out! It felt like it might have been a red herring, sometimes you just need another pair of eyes. Cheers.